# Why are many frequencies of light needed to create a short pulse?

Tags: photons, frequency

In looking at light sources, I am curious as to the relationship between pulse time and frequencies. My application is focused on two-photon fluorescence. Why does a short pulse of light require many different frequencies?

Comment: It is a property of Fourier transforms. Are you familiar with Fourier theory?